# Getting NaN when multiplying these two columns from different dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to multiply columns from two different dataframes into a new df. The first dataframe (df1) contains the prices for different items, and the column header is the date. The second dataframe (df2) contains the quantity of each item.

**df1**

```
Date     1990-01-03  1990-01-04  1990-01-05  ...  2020-04-09  2020-04-14  2020-04-15
AAAAAAA        1.11        1.11        1.09  ...      102.22      103.46      103.96
BBBBBBB         NaN         NaN         NaN  ...      308.70      314.95      314.10
CCCCCCC         NaN         NaN         NaN  ...       65.34       58.72       56.18
DDDDDDD        5.52        5.51        5.53  ...      104.50      106.03         NaN
EEEEEEE         NaN         NaN         NaN  ...     1211.45     1269.23         NaN
FFFFFFF         NaN         NaN         NaN  ...       36.14       36.85         NaN
GGGGGGG       93.35       94.37       94.37  ...     1564.00     1537.50     1482.50
HHHHHHH         NaN         NaN         NaN  ...       45.69       46.68       46.24
IIIIIII         NaN         NaN         NaN  ...       75.10       74.88       74.40
JJJJJJJ      328.76      328.25      327.74  ...     6168.00     6448.00     6296.00
KKKKKKK         NaN         NaN         NaN  ...       23.49       23.50       24.04
LLLLLLL        4.45        4.41        4.34  ...       36.55       35.96         NaN
MMMMMMM        1.96        1.96        1.94  ...      141.23      146.03         NaN
NNNNNNN        1.09        1.09        1.09  ...      267.99      287.05         NaN
OOOOOOO        1.09        1.09        1.08  ...      201.53      207.17         NaN
PPPPPPP         NaN         NaN         NaN  ...       98.00      100.80      100.50
QQQQQQQ         NaN         NaN         NaN  ...      129.00      128.40      124.20
RRRRRRR         NaN         NaN         NaN  ...      140.60      141.45      139.60
[18 rows x 7658 columns]
```

and **df2**

```
Symbol  Average Purchase Price  Quantity
0   AAAAAAA                  49.980     320.0
1   BBBBBBB                 239.125     120.0
2   CCCCCCC                 223.040      40.0
3   DDDDDDD                  90.370     100.0
4   EEEEEEE                 701.300      10.0
5   FFFFFFF                  35.150     120.0
6   GGGGGGG                1259.000     700.0
7   HHHHHHH                  32.050     250.0
8   IIIIIII                  53.300     240.0
9   JJJJJJJ                6805.000     130.0
10  KKKKKKK                  27.590    1000.0
11  LLLLLLL                  82.120     170.0
12  MMMMMMM                 106.470     150.0
13  NNNNNNN                  95.970     308.0
14  OOOOOOO                  81.420     150.0
15  PPPPPPP                  39.690      60.0
16  QQQQQQQ                  35.270     104.0
17  RRRRRRR                  68.240      12.0
```

however when I use the function:

```
date = '2020-04-14'
total = df2[['Quantity']].mul(df1[date], axis=0)
print(total)
```

(Ideally, I'd like to do it for every date but I'm just learning so I thought I'd start out with one date)

I get:

```
Quantity
0             NaN
1             NaN
2             NaN
3             NaN
4             NaN
5             NaN
6             NaN
7             NaN
8             NaN
9             NaN
10            NaN
11            NaN
12            NaN
13            NaN
14            NaN
15            NaN
16            NaN
17            NaN
AAAAAAA       NaN
BBBBBBB       NaN
CCCCCCC       NaN
DDDDDDD       NaN
EEEEEEE       NaN
FFFFFFF       NaN
GGGGGGG       NaN
HHHHHHH       NaN
IIIIIII       NaN
JJJJJJJ       NaN
KKKKKKK       NaN
LLLLLLL       NaN
MMMMMMM       NaN
NNNNNNN       NaN
OOOOOOO       NaN
PPPPPPP       NaN
QQQQQQQ       NaN
RRRRRRR       NaN
```

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a problem of indexes. The index column of the product dataframe is an evidence that `Symbol` is the index for the first dataframe, while the second has a sequential index. Assuming that no repetition of the symbol occurs in either dataframe, you could set `Symbol` as the index in the second one

```
date = '2020-04-14'
total = df2.set_index('Symbol')[['Quantity']].mul(df1[date], axis=0)
print(total)
```

it gives:

```
          Quantity
Symbol            
AAAAAAA    33107.2
BBBBBBB    37794.0
CCCCCCC     2348.8
DDDDDDD    10603.0
EEEEEEE    12692.3
FFFFFFF     4422.0
GGGGGGG  1076250.0
HHHHHHH    11670.0
IIIIIII    17971.2
JJJJJJJ   838240.0
KKKKKKK    23500.0
LLLLLLL     6113.2
MMMMMMM    21904.5
NNNNNNN    88411.4
OOOOOOO    31075.5
PPPPPPP     6048.0
QQQQQQQ    13353.6
RRRRRRR     1697.4
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in indexing - your data frames have got different indices. To make your code work, unify indices in both data frames by [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) method. You can use the following code.

```
>>> df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

The code will change index in `df1` on integers from 0 to 17, which will be the same index as `df2` has got.

Comment: You just have to pray for the order to be the same in both dataframes...